Assistance Required for Mapping Product Table with Custom Table
I have a requirement where I need to map the existing product table to a new custom table. However, I am unable to locate the model class for the product table in the code base where I can add a column to establish a foreign key relationship.
Could you please assist me with this?
Need to add the new column in the Product Entity
